# Entity Framework Code First Membership Provider Relationship Issue

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-membership

I'm trying to code first on asp.net membership provider.  When code first creates the table, it generates all tables and appropriate relationship to the bridge table but it also create an additional relationship from the AspNet_User(one) to Aspnet_Role(many).  Do you know why it doing this?  There shouldn't be any relationship between user and role table.

```
public class Aspnet_Role
{
    public Aspnet_Role()
    {
        Aspnet_Users = new HashSet<Aspnet_Users>();
    }
    [Key]
    public Guid RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public string LoweredRoleName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Aspnet_Users> Aspnet_Users { get; set; }
}
public class Aspnet_Users
{
    public Aspnet_Users()
    {
        Aspnet_Roles = new HashSet<Aspnet_Role>();
    }
    [Key]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string LoweredUserName { get; set; }
    public string MobileAlias { get; set; }
    public bool IsAnonymous { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastActivityDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Aspnet_Membership Aspnet_Membership { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Aspnet_Role> Aspnet_Roles { get; set; }
}
public class StagingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Aspnet_Role> Aspnet_Roles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Aspnet_Users> Aspnet_Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)

    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Aspnet_Users>()
            .HasMany(r => r.Aspnet_Roles)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(m => m.ToTable("aspnet_UsersInRoles")
                .MapRightKey("RoleId")
                .MapLeftKey("UserId"));

    }
}
```

Comment: Why shouldn't there be a relationship between user and its roles?

Comment: The relationship should only be on the bridge table not on the parent tables. Which it (aspnet_user) has a one to many relationship to (aspnet_userinroles) and (aspnet_role) has a one to many relationship to aspnet_userinroles).  But entity create another relationship bewteen aspnet_user to aspnet_roles which I do not want this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the navigation property on the WithMany extension.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

     modelBuilder.Entity<Aspnet_Users>()
         .HasMany(r => r.Aspnet_Roles)
         .WithMany(u => u.Aspnet_Users)
         .Map(m => m.ToTable("aspnet_UsersInRoles")
         .MapRightKey("RoleId")
          .MapLeftKey("UserId")); 

}
```